# Slow Processing

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, bitconverter

Well, I'm trying to convert various data "bytes" to "long".
And it seems to be very slow ...

Code:

```
    For X = 0 To Map.MaxX
        For Y = 0 To Map.MaxY
            Map.Tile(X, Y).Data1 = Buffer.ReadLong
            Map.Tile(X, Y).Data2 = Buffer.ReadLong
            Map.Tile(X, Y).Data3 = Buffer.ReadLong
            Map.Tile(X, Y).DirBlock = Buffer.ReadLong
            ReDim Map.Tile(X, Y).Layer(0 To MapLayer.Layer_Count - 1)
            For i = 0 To MapLayer.Layer_Count - 1
                Map.Tile(X, Y).Layer(i).tileset = Buffer.ReadLong
                Map.Tile(X, Y).Layer(i).X = Buffer.ReadLong
                Map.Tile(X, Y).Layer(i).Y = Buffer.ReadLong
            Next
            Map.Tile(X, Y).Type = Buffer.ReadLong
        Next
    Next
```

Converter:

```
Public Function ReadLong(Optional ByVal peek As Boolean = True) As Long
    If Buff.Count > readpos Then 'check to see if this passes the byte count
        Dim ret As Long = BitConverter.ToInt64(Buff.ToArray, readpos)
        If peek And Buff.Count > readpos Then
            readpos += 8
        End If
        Return ret
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Byte Buffer Past Limit!") 'past byte count throw a new exception
    End If
End Function
```

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Comment: What makes you think that this is slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is that you are calling `buff.ToArray` each time you read a long value. The `ToArray` method will make a copy of the buffer each time. You should call `ToArray` before you start processing the map and use the array instance when calling the `BitConverter.ToInt64` method.